# Get reference to my WPF ListBox's ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollview

How can I get a reference to my `ListBox`'s `ScrollViewer` in C#? I've tried pretty much everything I can think of. The ListBox is in a WPF custom control so we use `Template.FindName` to get references to all our controls. My `ListBox` looks like this:

```xml
<ListBox
 x:Name="PART_SoundList" 
 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
 Focusable="False"
 FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
 BorderThickness="0" 
 ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource ListBoxItemAlternatingStyleSelector}"
 ItemsSource="{Binding}">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="850" Focusable="False" Panel.ZIndex="999"  >
                <WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX=".75" ScaleY=".57" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Focusable="False" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScroller}"   >
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Focusable="False" Panel.ZIndex="999"  />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>

</ListBox>
```

`Template.FindName("Scroller", this) as ScrollViewer` results in `null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you need a reference to the ScrollViewer for? Only curious because there may be a different approach you could take to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably try to get a reference to the ScrollViewer too soon. Try to move your code in the loaded event and check if it still returns null:

in your customControl/form constructor:

```
this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var x = PART_SoundList.Template.FindName("Scroller", PART_SoundList);
}
```

Comment: I can't find `.Findname` after Template! Any idea what I a missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the XAML you have above is part of the ControlTemplate for your CustomControl, right?  I would also assume that you're getting the control parts on the OnApplyTemplate() method, right?  If this is the case, then, I think what you need to do is to force a call to PART_SoundList.ApplyTemplate() before finding the ScrollViewer.  So, the code for your Custom Control should look something like this:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    private ListBox lb;
    private ScrollViewer scroller;

    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        lb = this.Template.FindName("PART_SoundList", this) as ListBox;
        lb.ApplyTemplate();
        scroller = lb.Template.FindName("Scroller", lb) as ScrollViewer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice I didn't now about ApplyTemplate(). Claudiu's answer is working for me right now but I'm sure I'll be able to use this down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursive call to Visual Tree to grab any Visual from the tree.

```
public static ChildItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where ChildItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is ChildItem)
            return (ChildItem)child;
        else
        {
            ChildItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<ChildItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This gives you a generic method to get Visual element of type mentioned from the Visual tree.

Comment: I tried that (both your method and my variation of it earlier today) and it's still null.

Comment: This solution is from MSDN's documentation for [FrameworkTemplate.FindName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx).

Comment: Child item needs to be captilized in generic type specifier. ie, <ChildItem> not <childItem>

Comment: ChildItem could not be found -

Answer (score 1):

For those who got here seeking an answer to the original question:

In C#

```
ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(MyListBox);
```

or in VB

```
Dim sv As ScrollViewer = FindVisualChild(Of ScrollViewer)(MyListBox)
```

Where in XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
</ListBox>
```

Comment: What is this `FindVisualChild` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the reference to scroll/check viewport size the [IScrollProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.iscrollprovider.aspx) should be sufficient for you.

You can access it like this in your code behind (Note Claudiu point of waiting til the loaded event):

```
ListBoxAutomationPeer svAutomation = (ListBoxAutomationPeer)ScrollViewerAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(PART_SoundList);
// not feeling creative with my var names today...
IScrollProvider scrollInterface = (IScrollProvider)svAutomation.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Scroll);
```

Then scroll horizontally and vertically whenever you want and to your hearts content.