# Windows Phone ListBox: how to scroll it?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scroll

I've got a ListBox (dynamically populated via code):

(i can't insert the code, bah)

I need, with a button, to move this listbox vertically. The listbox have a fixed height, and also the items.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per MSDN, it looks like this is a viable answer for you?
[ListBox.ScrollIntoView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Edit - Comment Summary of Answer: The question here was targetting scrolling itself, not to a particular object. As such, the necessary action was to attain a reference to the ListBox's ScrollViewer. From there, a call needed to be placed to the ScrollViewer's ScrollToVerticalOffset method. As the OP wanted to scroll down a certain amount from the original position, the ScrollViewer's VerticalOffset property was incorporated into the call.

Comment: i don't know how to use it...
For example: if a user push the button, i need to scroll the listbox by 300 pixel.

Comment: Ok so you want to move a certain amount, rather than to a specific object. Seems like you'll need to attain a reference to the ListBox's ScrollViewer. From there, you can call the ScrollViewer's [ScrollToVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method. If you need to scroll down a certian amount from the current position, then you'll probably be referencing the [VerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset(v=vs.95).aspx) property as well.

Comment: Yes, it's this that i want :-)
but now i must add the scrollview element in the XAML?
because now my XAML is:
        <ListBox Name="listavideo" Margin="0,115,0,0" Height="680">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
//template of an item
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
And there's no other thing related to my ListBox in this XAML

Comment: Yeah, [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963341/get-reference-to-my-wpf-listboxs-scrollviewer-in-c) has some code you can reference for that, if you need.

Comment: I''ve done it!
I've sorrounded my listbox with ScrollViewer, than in the click button:
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.my_list_name, 0);
            var sv = child as ScrollViewer;
            sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset + 4);
4 is because i have 3 items per page.

Thanks a lot...

Hey, there's a way i can block the scrolling of the listbox with the finger?

Comment: Property:VerticalScrollBarVisibility   Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a vertical ScrollBar should be displayed.

Comment: Zak - Be careful how you are dealing with this kind of behaviour.  Microsoft put a lot of effort into making sure user experience is the same across applications.  Modifying the behaviour of a ListBox in this way may be the best way to achieve the functionality you want, but you may alienate users who are expecting the default behaviour.  In the end it is up to you how you implement things, but be aware that user expectation can be a powerful ally or a bitter enemy.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't think I really needed to mention that, since you were already aware how to attain a reference to the ScrollViewer.

Comment: it's only because i'm new in WP7

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Set the ListBox to not scroll, then add a ScrollViewer around it.  Now in your code behind you can set the ScrollViewer to whatever you want.

XAML:

```
<!--Disable the ListBox scroll and add a ScrollViewer so we have control over the scroll position.-->
    <ScrollViewer 
             Name="scrlvwrListBoxMessages"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListBox x:Name="lstbxMessages"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
</ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code:

```
    private void ScrollToBottom()
    {
        //Scroll to the bottom.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.scrlvwrListBoxMessages.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double.MaxValue);
        });
    }
```