# How to scroll a ListBox programmatically the same way the MouseWheelEvent does?

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok, I have the following problem:

I would like to scroll an overflowing ListBox up and down.

I would like to do it programatically in a custom control inheriting from  ListBox. I've seen and tested things such as `scrollIntoView`. However I would like to have a scrolling similar to what you can have when using the mouse's wheel.

I don't want to have the mouse involved at all (I'm developing for the Kinect, and since there are 2 cursors, I don't want to use the Mouse event args)

a google search didn't turn up much: I've read plenty of thread on how to scroll in code behind using scrollIntoView, or putting a scrollbar and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will involve two steps:

1. Find the scrollViewer control inside listBox template
2. Perform the actual scrolling in that scrollViewer

For the first step implementation please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963341/get-reference-to-my-wpf-listboxs-scrollviewer-in-c). Here is the code snippet extracted from there:

```
this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = listbox.Template.FindName("Scroller", listbox);
}
```

And for the second step you should use one of the methods from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer_methods), `LineDown` or `PageDown` probably.

P.S.: I haven't tested this approach at all since I do not have VS installed so feel free to add the needed code here.

Comment: I've check and you're right I have to use the scrollViewer in order to scroll my list the way the wheel does: see [the scrollViewer class](http://wikiencyclopedia.net/4.0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ScrollViewer.cs/1305600/ScrollViewer.cs). I haven't implemented it yet since I'm going to make a custom scrollViewer for the custom ListBox. Based on [tequilarapido's work](http://kinectwpf.codeplex.com/).